# Can not get custom information in Authentication of spring-security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

this is my `AuthenticationProvider` in authorization server

```java
@Service
public class UmUserAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("UmUserDetailsService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

        long userId = (new SecurityUtil()).checkUser(umUserMapper, username, password);
        if (userId <= 0) {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("login failed");
        }
        UserDetails user = userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        //I've try different ways to put user detail in here
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null,
                user.getAuthorities());
        auth.setDetails(user);
        return auth;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }

}
```

and this is my resource server, I cant get what I set in `Authentication`,

`getPrincipal` is `String`

`getDetails` is type of `org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationDetails`

```java
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class UserController {



    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getRouters() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        logger.info(auth.getPrincipal().toString());
        logger.info(auth.getDetails().toString());


        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();

        return jo.toString();
    }
```

the logger print
[image]

so How cat I get the custom detail in `Authentication`?

Comment: what kind of auth do you whant to implement? JWT? In my opinion this is a strange a weird solution to implement authentication in spring security

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I solve this problem in a trick way

whatever I set in `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken`, I got the type of `String`,  So I fill it with json string;

```java
UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                new JSONObject(user).toString(), password, userDetailService.getAuthorities(username));
```

so I can parse json string at the controller.

But I still want to know what cause it

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that you are setting the `UserDetails` on authentication, but it is overriden by the default.

A custom authentication converter might be the solution.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, AbstractAuthenticationToken> {

    @Override
    public AbstractAuthenticationToken convert(@NotNull final Jwt jwt) {
        String username = jwt.getClaimAsString("username");
        UserDetails user = userDetailService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken (jwt, user, userDetailService.getAuthorities(username)));
    }

}
```